# Planar Quartic Curve invariants for number of connex components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, plane-curves

I have some affine planar quartic curves over $\mathbb{R}$ (of the general form $a x^4 + b x^3y + c x^2 y^2 + d xy^3 + e y^4 + fx^3 + g x^2y + h xy^2 + i y^3 + j x^2 + k xy + l y^2 + m x + n y + p= 0$ with $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l, m,n,p)\in \mathbb{R}^{15}$) that I know for sure describes either:

- The empty set
- 1 point
- 2 points
- 3 points
- 4 points

This is the case because it is the sum of the square of two different conics, so it describes the intersection which cannot be a full overlap.

I would like to *count* those points (using a closed form if possible).

I thought about finding some invariant describing the number of connected component of the curve or something like that (maybe the number of bitangent too, knowing that not every quartic get 28 bitangents), but I could not find a reference listing the known invariants of the planar quartics *and* describing them.

Does anyone have a reference of that sort?

Comment: You need to add a significant amount of detail here. For instance, typically when one thinks of plane quartics, they're over an algebraically closed field and have infinitely many points, not at most four, so that's something you need to explain. (The number of bitangents is also rather well-known to be 28 for a general plane quartic - search "bitangents of a quartic" or "28 bitangents" and you will see lots of information.)

Comment: I am sorry but I have been perfectly clear, I am talking about a planar quartic curve, so of the form $a x^4 + b x^3y + c x^2 y^2 + d xy^3 + e y^4 + fx^3 + g x^2y + h xy^2 + i x^2 + j xy + k y + l = 0$ for which the solution is a finite set of points, which is the case when you sum the square of two conics for instance. Also the number of bitangent is *at most* 28, not always 28.

Comment: I updated the original post to make sure to lower the chances misunderstanding.

Comment: You have not included your field of definition here. If you are working over $\Bbb R$, you need to say so - most people in algebraic geometry when reading this sort of question will assume an algebraically closed base field unless explicitly told otherwise.